# Are import statements replacing script tags in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
import something from './something'
```

versus

```
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js'></script>
```

I personally find that npm installing something and using modules/compiling is a bit of a hassle when I can just use a remote CDN or use a local file along with a script tag. But I'm wondering if javascript is moving towards import statements or will script tags stay?

Are library providers moving to only use npm, or will their libraries also have a way to just src a single script file? Will they need to support both?

Comment: they're not really comparable. They have different functions and serve different purposes

Comment: Both are available and both will be available. Modules are nicer and that's partly because they are newer. They provide better encapsulation and some other features. But the script tags are still a thing and are extremely unlikely to ever go away.

Comment: @VLAZ do imports always require compilation?

Comment: [Not necessarily](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-es-modules/) but that doesn't work in IE.

Answer (score 3):

An initial `<script>` tag is necessary regardless - that is, your

```
import something from './something'
```

must be in a (modular) `<script>` as well. So, at the very least, `<script>` tags will never *completely* go away.

The biggest problem with using `import` is that it requires browsers to understand the syntax. JS modules are not bleeding-edge anymore, but they're not supported everywhere either. See [MDN's compatibility tables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Browser_compatibility). Not supported on IE at all (of course), only supported on Chrome 61+ (released late 2017), with other modern browsers supporting it around a generally similar time period. Once you can count on *all* users you want your site to be usable for to have browsers that support `import`, switching to `import` instead of importing a library or another `<script>` tag is an option. Otherwise, those with older browsers will not be able to use your site, and it may take many years for those incompatible browsers to die off.

It's ultimately up to you - it's a trade-off between the (very slight) convenience of using `import` syntax, and the ability of those with older browsers to use your site.

There are other things to consider as well, though. Every `import` of a library and every `<script>` tag with a `src` means one more network request, which means more loading time before the site is fully functional. If you wish to minimize the number of network requests (which can be very important for users on mobile or with bad connections, when the connection is over http/1.1), you'll have to put *all* the Javascript into a single file that gets sent to a client. This can be done with module bundlers like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/).

(if you wanted to go the extra mile and put *everything* into a single inline `<script>`, so that only a single request from the client is necessary to load the whole page and its functionality, that's an option too - this sort of thing is often seen on huge websites)

As long as your script-writing includes a build process (which it probably should, for anything professional and non-trivial - it allows you to write in the latest and greatest version of the language, while still permitting obsolete browsers to understand your code), I think you *may as well* install libraries locally with NPM and bundle them together. Once you understand the tooling, it doesn't have any downside.